# Dequeue cells more than default UICollectionView dequeued cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Is there a way to dequeue more cells than default UICollectionView dequeued cells? For example in the picture below UICollectionView dequeues showing cell, one before and one after. Is there a way to dequeue more than this three cells?`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, prefetchItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) { print("Prefetch: \(indexPaths)") }`

only gives me one indexpath after. What I need is to create four or five cells after and before showing cells to Implement my functionality before cell is shown.
[image: picture of showing cells]

Comment: Dequeue is called when needed: ~when the cell needs to be shown. This avoid loading more than necessary (and it means less CPU uses, so faster, so less battery, etc.). Although, by expanding the `contentSize` of your collectionView, you might be able to force that dequeue. Because it's more in fact when the cell enters the contentSize part if I remember correctly. Then a few more tricks would be needed to avoid not showing some top/bottom part of the collectionView content.

Comment: @Paulw11 as I already said prefetching gives me one indexpath ahead. What I need is to be able to access cells further more than one indexpath ahead like four or five

Comment: @OmidKia: *Why* do you need that?

Comment: @MartinR each of my cells contain an instance of AVPlayer to play a video. I need a cell to be instantiated fully with AVPlayer to be prepared and played whenever it's visible.

Comment: @Larme I guess increasing the contentSize would result in creating unwanted white space at the bottom of my collectionView which I suppose is not a clean workaround of this matter

Answer (score 0):

An [official Apple sample code](https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/89a057b5b7/BrowsingAndModifyingPhotoAlbums.zip) shows a technique that you might find useful. Instead of relying on `UICollectionView` to receive callbacks and load data as needed, you can observe scrolling and based on `contentOffset` value, you will know how much look ahead you need.

Copy pasting relevant parts here in case link isn't available for a future reader. All of this lives inside a `UICollectionViewController` subclass - it can be adapted to work with any `UIScrollView` in general.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // This is your trigger point
    updateCachedAssets()
}
```

```
var fetchResult: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>!
fileprivate let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()
fileprivate let thumbnailSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
fileprivate var previousPreheatRect = CGRect.zero
fileprivate func updateCachedAssets() {
    // Update only if the view is visible.
    guard isViewLoaded && view.window != nil else { return }
    
    // The window you prepare ahead of time is twice the height of the visible rect.
    let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: collectionView!.contentOffset, size: collectionView!.bounds.size)
    let preheatRect = visibleRect.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: -0.5 * visibleRect.height)
        
    // Update only if the visible area is significantly different from the last preheated area.
    let delta = abs(preheatRect.midY - previousPreheatRect.midY)
    guard delta > view.bounds.height / 3 else { return }
    
    // Compute the assets to start and stop caching.
    let (addedRects, removedRects) = differencesBetweenRects(previousPreheatRect, preheatRect)
    let addedAssets = addedRects
        .flatMap { rect in collectionView!.indexPathsForElements(in: rect) }
        .map { indexPath in fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.item) }
    let removedAssets = removedRects
        .flatMap { rect in collectionView!.indexPathsForElements(in: rect) }
        .map { indexPath in fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.item) }
        
    // Update the assets the PHCachingImageManager is caching.
    imageManager.startCachingImages(for: addedAssets,
                                    targetSize: thumbnailSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil)
    imageManager.stopCachingImages(for: removedAssets,
                                   targetSize: thumbnailSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil)
    // Store the computed rectangle for future comparison.
    previousPreheatRect = preheatRect
}
```

```
fileprivate func differencesBetweenRects(_ old: CGRect, _ new: CGRect) -> (added: [CGRect], removed: [CGRect]) {
    if old.intersects(new) {
        var added = [CGRect]()
        if new.maxY > old.maxY {
            added += [CGRect(x: new.origin.x, y: old.maxY,
                             width: new.width, height: new.maxY - old.maxY)]
        }
        if old.minY > new.minY {
            added += [CGRect(x: new.origin.x, y: new.minY,
                             width: new.width, height: old.minY - new.minY)]
        }
        var removed = [CGRect]()
        if new.maxY < old.maxY {
            removed += [CGRect(x: new.origin.x, y: new.maxY,
                               width: new.width, height: old.maxY - new.maxY)]
        }
        if old.minY < new.minY {
            removed += [CGRect(x: new.origin.x, y: old.minY,
                               width: new.width, height: new.minY - old.minY)]
        }
        return (added, removed)
    } else {
        return ([new], [old])
    }
}
```

##### Notes

> 0. The code is several years old and you will need to adapt this to your requirements.
> 1. You can adjust the preheatRect compute to be what fits your needs.
>
> ```
> // The window you prepare ahead of time is twice the height of the visible rect.
> let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: collectionView!.contentOffset, size: collectionView!.bounds.size)
> let preheatRect = visibleRect.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: -0.5 * visibleRect.height)
> ```
>
> 2. The sample implements this `preheatRect` logic for preloading `PHAsset` thumbnails. You need to adapt your dataSource to a similar style and start/stop loading your resources.